# Error restarting SAMBA, requires force

Tags: centos, samba, systemctl

Under CentOS 7, I am running a SAMBA server. Recently, likely after some updates, has become a bit less stable. The log shows periodically:

```
change_to_user_internal: chdir_current_service() failed!
```

The service doesn't necessarily fail, but becomes slow and unreliable. Running

```
systemctl restart samba
```

has resulted in very slow service restart times, with

```
Stopping Samba SMB Daemon...
smb.service stop-final-sigterm timed out. Killing.
```

in the log. The service eventually restarts, but seems to have to go through an internal process of elevation of kill until it gets there. Is there anything that explains the initial `chdir` routines failing, and whether this is related to the slow access times and/or difficulty killing/restarting SAMBA?

Note I am running OpenVPN to access these resources remotely, but the access failures are both local and remote.

Comment: You may need to add `force user = [user]` to your `samba.conf` if the error is related to `uid.c:448(change_to_user_internal)` . There should be a line either preceding or following the `chdir` error that provides additional info.

Comment: What you have in /var/log/samba/log.smbd ? Eventually also check what do you have in /var/log/messages There you should have more detailed error. 

Other possibility can be that your samba shared directory has a directory above which is not readable by a samba-user (no execution [x] permission set) so samba-user cannot get (cd) into the directory. The solution is easy sudo chmod+x on the directory above the samba shared directory. Also check permissions to the samba directory by command ls -al /path/to/samba/shared/directory

Comment: please provide full error log.